# How to interpret an expression when the radical doesn't extend over anything?

Tags: radicals, radical-equations

I have a school assignment which includes solving this problem from a scanned document:

[image: ambiguous root image]

Equivalent:

> Given that $m = { \sqrt{} l  - n^2 \over n }$,
> express $n$ in terms of $m$.

How do interpret this formula?
Is it

1. $m = {\sqrt l - n^2 \over n}$ or
2. $m = {\sqrt{l - n^2} \over n}$?

As an aside, I can only find a solution when assuming it is 2.

Comment: I bet it is 1. It is easy to solve, considering it is just a quadratic formula

Comment: Honestly could be either. I would lean towards 2 because the answer is less ugly, but 1 is a perfectly valid problem to have posed.

Comment: This is very bad notation.  You should ask the instructor.

Comment: I agree with @eyeballfrog that 2 is more likely. You can answer the assignment with a complete answer like "If what is meant is xxx then the answer is yyy. If the proper reading is www then the answer is zzz." As a teacher I would love to see that.

Comment: I wonder if it is significant that the radical is not part of the expression over the vinculum?  That is, the typeset document appears to be something more like
$$ \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{{\sqrt{\vphantom{l-n^2}}}}{\vphantom{n}} \frac{l - n^2}{n},$$
rather than
$$ \frac{\sqrt{}l -n^2}{n}. $$
As such, I would lean towards the second interpretation (everything above the vinculum is part of the radicand).  However, the notation is terribly ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is inescapably ambiguous, so, as in comments, you can either ask  your instructor how they want it interpreted, or give two different answers, with explanations about the ambiguity. Probably a typesetting error, but... :

One historical point is that people really have written something like $\sqrt{}\,2$, that is, without the horizontal bar part of the symbol, for $\sqrt{2}$, historically.